# Restricting which classes are considered as model classes in EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a large number of classes, some of which are model classes and some of which are not. I'm trying to get only the model classes to work with a DB using EF6. Getting over the minor inconvenience that I can't have both `ModelNamespace1.ClassA` and `ModelNamespace2.ClassB` (I got over this by using Fluent API's `Ignore<>()` method on the `ModelBuilder` instance), I'm now facing the problem that classes which are not supposed to be part of the model classes are considered as such.

As a result of this, after my custom code in `OnModelCreating()` finishes executing, I get this exception for many classes which are not even part of my model (conceptually):

`System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
Translation.Tester.RuleResult: : EntityType 'RuleResult' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.`

Why is this happening, what am I doing wrong and is there a way to restrict EF to only considering classes in a list of namespaces (e.g. `ModelNamespace1.*`, `ModelNamespace2.*` but not `NonModelNamespace.*`)?

My guess is that it's looking at every class that's being referenced from my model classes assemblies and considering that for mapping as well.

**Later edit:**

Having consulted [EF code](https://github.com/mono/entityframework/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/ModelConfiguration/Mappers/TypeMapper.cs#L23) It seems that after `OnModelCreating()` is called, when types are actually mapped, an instance of the `TypeMapper` class is created internally, the constructor of which looks like this:

```
public TypeMapper(MappingContext mappingContext)
{
    DebugCheck.NotNull(mappingContext);

    _mappingContext = mappingContext;

    _knownTypes.AddRange(
        mappingContext.ModelConfiguration
                      .ConfiguredTypes
                      .Select(t => t.Assembly)
                      .Distinct()
                      .SelectMany(a => a.GetAccessibleTypes().Where(type => type.IsValidStructuralType())));
}
```

This code leads to loading all accessible types from the assemblies where model classes are defined. This results in having known types which are not part of the model.

Comment: You should inherit all model classes from IEntity interface, in order to differentiate them from other classes.

Comment: Keep all your model classes in a single class library and any other helpers or Data Transfer Objects in other libraries

Comment: If you haven't created a DbSet for a class then EF should not even know about it.

Comment: Isn't there a type discovery mechanism in place as indicated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx)? Would this discovery mechanism navigate to referenced assemblies and include classes from there? It seems that I'm experiencing something of this nature.